# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd use date type variable

Tags: sql, powershell

I don't know how to use Powershell variable in Invoke-Sqlcmd.
I have see in [msdn emxample:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx)

```
 $MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT `$(MyVar1) AS Var1, `$(MyVar2) AS Var2;" -Variable $MyArray
```

,but it seems not what I need.And I also can not understand the example , `$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'"`  ,`MyVar1` is variable name and `String1` is the variable? fill to the sql command will be `SELECT MyVar1 = 'String1' AS Var1`;However, what does `var1` means?

My code:

```
$FirstDayOfLastMonth = (Get-Date -Day 1 -hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddMonths(-1)

$LastDayOfLastMonth = (Get-Date -Day 1 -hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).AddMonths(-1).AddDays([DateTime]::DaysInMonth($FirstDayOfLastMonth.year, $FirstDayOfLastMonth.month) - 1)

Write-Verbose "Invoke-Sqlcmd for winners"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query @"
    use iMAG;
    select L.Name AS LuckyDrawName, P.ParticipationTime, Z.Name as PrizeName, W.MobileNumber, T.ParticipantUniqueIdentifier
    FROM LuckyDrawWinner W
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipation P ON P.LuckyDrawParticipationId = W.LuckyDrawParticipationId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipant T ON T.LuckyDrawParticipantId = P.LuckyDrawParticipantId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawPrize Z ON Z.LuckyDrawPrizeId = W.LuckyDrawPrizeId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDraw L ON L.LuckyDrawId = Z.LuckyDrawId
    WHERE cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) < $LastDayOfLastMonth And cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) > $FirstDayOfLastMonth
    and L.LuckyDrawId IN (3) and Z.Grade <> 0
"@ | Export-Csv -Path $LuckyDrawWinnerReportFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Directly using `$LastDayOfLastMonth` does not work. I also try `cast($LastDayOfLastMonth AS date)` in Invoke-Sqlcmd .
Then try `$s = $FirstDayOfLastMonth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` ,then use `cast($s AS date)` .Both do not work.

output error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near '23'.
At D:\ScheduledTasks\EmailReport\DailyEmailReport.ps1:32 char:14
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd <<<<  -Query @"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

I'm new to powershell,this question maybe simple,but I have searched for invoke-sqlcmd date variable and other keywork for a long time with nothing useful found .
I'd be appreciated if you can help.

**update**:
I edit my code as msdn did:

```
$Vars="FirstDayOfLastMonth='$FirstDayOfLastMonth'", "LastDayOfLastMonth='$LastDayOfLastMonth'"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query @"
    use iMAG;
    select L.Name AS LuckyDrawName, P.ParticipationTime, Z.Name as PrizeName, W.MobileNumber, T.ParticipantUniqueIdentifier
    FROM LuckyDrawWinner W
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipation P ON P.LuckyDrawParticipationId = W.LuckyDrawParticipationId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipant T ON T.LuckyDrawParticipantId = P.LuckyDrawParticipantId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawPrize Z ON Z.LuckyDrawPrizeId = W.LuckyDrawPrizeId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDraw L ON L.LuckyDrawId = Z.LuckyDrawId
    WHERE cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) > $(FirstDayOfLastMonth) AND cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) < $(LastDayOfLastMonth)
    and L.LuckyDrawId IN (3) and Z.Grade <> 0
"@ -Variable $Vars | Export-Csv -Path $LuckyDrawWinnerReportFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

But it turns out:

```
The term 'FirstDayOfLastMonth' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
 the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\ScheduledTasks\EmailReport\iDQDailyEmailReport.ps1:45 char:20
+ FirstDayOfLastMonth <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (FirstDayOfLastMonth:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you first try to put string dates in your vars with this format:

```
$FirstDayOfLastMonth.tostring("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
$LastDayOfLastMonth.tostring("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
```

The idea is to to have a query string that look like the one you would use in your query manager. For your debug assigne the query to a string and print it.

```
$a = @"
    use iMAG;
    select L.Name AS LuckyDrawName, P.ParticipationTime, Z.Name as PrizeName, W.MobileNumber, T.ParticipantUniqueIdentifier
    FROM LuckyDrawWinner W
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipation P ON P.LuckyDrawParticipationId = W.LuckyDrawParticipationId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawParticipant T ON T.LuckyDrawParticipantId = P.LuckyDrawParticipantId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDrawPrize Z ON Z.LuckyDrawPrizeId = W.LuckyDrawPrizeId
    INNER JOIN LuckyDraw L ON L.LuckyDrawId = Z.LuckyDrawId
    WHERE cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) < $LastDayOfLastMonth And cast(P.ParticipationTime AS date) > $FirstDayOfLastMonth
    and L.LuckyDrawId IN (3) and Z.Grade <> 0
"@

write-host $a

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $a | Export-Csv -Path $LuckyDrawWinnerReportFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

---

Edited

$(FirstDayOfLastMonth) means nothing in your context, you should use `($FirstDayOfLastMonth)` or `$($FirstDayOfLastMonth)`

Comment: Thank you for answer.After I cast $LastDayOfLastMonth to date, It realy worked.Would you mind to explain my update question?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without awkward formatting:

```
$timevariable = get-date

$MyArray = "MyVar1 =  '$timevariable' "

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query "insert SomeTable (datetimecolumn) VALUES (`$(MyVar1));" -Variable $MyArray -Verbose
```